# Understanding Game Center Sandbox

Tags: ios

I am trying to see submitted scores in sandboxed leaderboard. For iOS5 I read that 2 accounts are required to submit scores.
Now what I don't understand is whether I should see more than 1 players played the game. For now, all my efforts lead me to see only #1 of 1 player in leaderboard list and I see "no scores".
In other words, should sandboxed environment ever show more than 1 player?

Details are below:

- Using iOS5
- Created 3 different accounts and submitted scores from them
- Accounts have e-mails verified
- Tried on Simulator and iPad
- Tried both, developer and distribution certificates
- Waited more than 24 hours
- Checked from Game Center app and from Game Center view controller inside my app.
- Can see my score if I run my app on iOS 6

What else I should do to see submitted scores on iOS5 in leaderboard?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially 2 things to check. First is the time scope of the scores you are pulling. Is it set to "GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime"?

The second is the player scope. Do you have it set to "GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal"?

Comment: I am not using the `timeScope` property in view controller, neither I'm using GKLeaderBoard class. Now suddenly I can see the scores, but there are 2 events and I need to understand which one affected. a. I've created 4 users instead of 3. b. more than 24 hours passed.

Answer (score 0):

GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime is a default value. so it doesn't matter wether U set it or not=) check it out in documentation ))